# Compile-Time List of Keywords By Function Name

Tags: c++, string, list, compilation

This one is out there a bit, but thought I would ask. I have spent 6 hours looking for a solution, but have found nothing applicable. I have a situation where a submodule of the main code will be replaceable, with re-compile, by a similar version. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

// g++ -std=c++1z -o list *.cpp

class Foo
{
public:
  std::string funcA() {
    // Do important stuff
    int choice = 0;
    switch(choice){
      case 0:
        return "KeywordX";
        break;
      case 1:
        return "KeywordY";
        break;
      case 2:
        return "KeywordZ";
        break;
    }
  }

  std::string funcB() {
    std::string val1 = std::string(__func__) + "-KeywordY";
    std::string val2 = std::string(__func__) + "-KeywordZ";
    std::string val3 = std::string(__func__) + "-KeywordQ";
    // Do other important stuff
    int choice = 1;
    switch(choice){
      case 0:
        return val1;
        break;
      case 1:
        return val2;
        break;
      case 2:
        return val3;
        break;
    }
  }


};

int main ()
{
  Foo foo;
  printf("funcA = %s\n", foo.funcA().c_str());
  printf("funcB = %s\n", foo.funcB().c_str());
}
```

In the above code sample, the main code will be given a new version of the class Foo to perform unique processing, and it will always have the same list of function names (like funcA, funcB), but there may be 50 or more of them. The functions will perform some processing, and then return an appropriate keyword, as shown in funcA ('choice' is the result of the processing), which the main code will respond to. The main code was given a UML file that lists the keywords and the appropriate responses.

The issue here, is that the Foo class may have one or more typos, or a particular function may return a keyword that is not valid for it to return, and the main code won't know this until some random set of events causes that keyword to be returned. So, it would be nice to have a way to know at code startup, the list of all keywords, by function, that may be returned, so this can be compared to the UML file, and error raised. The funcB example resolves the 'by function' issue, but still doesn't make it accessible at startup.

Ideally, a list/map of all keywords, sorted by function would be nice, but even all this info concatenated to a string, that can be parsed at startup would work.

Yes, a master list of keywords, that was referenced for each return would solve the 'typo' issue, but not resolve the selection of wrong keyword.

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: How about enum, and a single function to translate enum to string?

Comment: "it would be nice to have a way to know at code startup, the list of all keywords, by function, that may be returned". The "Halting Problem" already states that you don't even know **if** a given function returns, let alone **what** it returns. Part of the problem is that your functions return a `std::string` which apparently can have invalid values. If they'd return a `Keyword` object, and that class had no invalid values, you'd have prevented the return of invalid values. You could still have an infinite loop in `funcA` , of course.

Comment: I have some push-back, so converting string to Keyword class is possible, but as has been stated, it doesn't solve the issue of returning an incorrect, but valid, keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce that the everything that can be returned by the function must be listed beforehand. With some clever manipulation, this list is accessible:

Example:
https://godbolt.org/z/frMEWo